# How to show a bootstrap modal via an Angular-Service

Tags: javascript, angular, error-handling, modal-dialog, inject

I have a global Errorhandler in which I process Client- and Server-Errors.

To provide a feedback for the user I want to open a modal which returns the error-message.

Therefore I've implemented a modal:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {BsModalRef, BsModalService} from 'ngx-bootstrap';
import {Button} from '../../layout-models/button.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'error-modal',
  templateUrl: './error-modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./error-modal.component.scss']
})
export class ErrorModalComponent {
  title: string;
  buttonTitle = 'OK';
  type: 'error';
  button: Button;

  protected modalRef: BsModalRef;

  constructor(protected modalService: BsModalService) {}

  public show(title: string, message: string) {
    this.title = title;
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(
      message,
      Object.assign({}, { class: `modal-banner ${this.type}`})
    );
  }

  hide() {
    if (this.modalRef) {
      this.modalRef.hide();
    }
  }
}
```

In my Notification-Service:

```
import {Injectable, NgZone} from '@angular/core';
import { ErrorModalComponent } from '../error-modal.component';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NotificationService {

  public errorModalComponent: ErrorModalComponent;

  showError(title: string, message: string): void {
     this.errorModalComponent.show(title, message);
  }
}
```

Which leads to 

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined`

I feel like I am doing some fundamental mistake - the main purpose of this is to have a centralized modal. Is this possible or do I need to use the ModalComponent in every Component in which I want to show the error-handling-modal?

Comment: You can use an observable in your service to determine when to show and hide the modal.  The modal would be at the root of the (`app.component`).  In the `app.component.ts` you would subscribe to that observable and show/hide the modal based on the value received from the subscription.

Comment: Can you please offer a simple example? This would help me a lot - I'm not that familiar with subscribtions because I am pretty new to angular!

Comment: Here is a rough idea, you'll probably have to make changes. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9vnzma

Comment: Check this: https://gist.github.com/jnizet/15c7a0ab4188c9ce6c79ca9840c71c4e

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't use ngx-modal I would use [NgbModal](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/[NgbModal][1])

What yazantahhan means is something like this:

```js
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {NgbModal, NgbModalRef} from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";

@Injectable()
export class ErrorModalService {

  title: string;
  buttonTitle = "OK";
  type: "error";

  protected modalRef: NgbModalRef;

  constructor(protected modalService: NgbModal) {}

  public show(title: string, message: string) {
    this.title = title;
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.open(
      message
    );
  }

  hide() {
    if (this.modalRef) {
      this.modalRef.close();
    }
  }
}
```

Then inject and use it like this:

```js
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import {ErrorModalService} from "./ErrorModalService";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.scss"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = "testAngular";

  constructor(
    private errorModalService: ErrorModalService,
  ) {}


  showError() {
    this.errorModalService.show("title", "message");
  }
}
```

Don't forget to provide the service in your module

```js
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";

import { AppRoutingModule } from "./app-routing.module";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import {ErrorModalService} from "./ErrorModalService";
import {BsModalService} from "ngx-bootstrap/modal";
import {NgbModule} from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NgbModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    ErrorModalService,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Thank you cleared it up for me. The only question that is left then is - am I losing the ability to style the modal. Right now the reason that the modal is in a component is, that it is heavy styled. Where do I put the HTML aswell as the CSS?

Comment: No, not at all. You can still encapsulate the modal functionalities in an own component (like in the examples provided by ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples) und use the service for the error handling stuff. The only thing you would have to do is to inject the modalComponent into the service the same way the service is injected into the AppComponent in the example above. (Off course you also have to provide the component in you module)